# How to use multiple display primitives in directX 11?

Tags: 3d, directx-11

I am making a physics engine and using directX as my display platform. I am following rastertek tutorial for directX programming.

I was wondering if I can use multiple display primitives like combination of POINTLIST and LINELIST or TRIANGLELIST

Here's my code:

```
stride = sizeof(VertexType); 

offset = 0;


deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);


deviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);


deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many effect variations per frame as you like. The only limitation is that the data stays constant for a single draw call.

```
BindTriangleData();
deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
DrawPrimitives();

BindPointData();
deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTS);
DrawPrimitives();
```